# Facebook page fans get notification for each picture upload using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook's GraphAPI from C# to upload pictures to a **Facebook Page** right after they are taken, for each session (around 3-4 hours) I create a new album and on average I upload around 500 photos, which are uploaded one-by-one (not using batch).

The problem is that for each picture upload all my fans get a notification on their news feed, this means that for each session there news feed get flooded with 500 (sometimes even 900) "XXXX page has uploaded a new photo" posts, this drives people crazy... :/

The way I thought it was to suppose to work was to combine the posts to one "multiple pictures" post which shows multiple pictures collaged together (usually that's what I see on my news feed when someone posts multiple pictures even if it's one-by-one)

I searched for a settings that can prevent this and found nothing, I thought maybe I need to change something in the way I upload the pictures...

the code I am using for uploading:

```
FacebookMediaObject uploadObj = new FacebookMediaObject { FileName = fileInfo.Name, ContentType = IMAGE_CONTENT_TYPE };
uploadObj.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName));
IDictionary<String, Object> uploadParams = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
uploadParams.Add("message", comment);
uploadParams.Add("image", uploadObj);
JsonObject photo = (JsonObject)fbClient.Post(String.Format("/{0}/photos", albumId), uploadParams);
```

I am using the access token of the page taken from the manager using the "accounts api"

Thanks.

Comment: I am stuck :/ could not find any information on this, if anyone have any idea please answer (anything i can try)